# How to extract three fields of text using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract 3 fields from a snippet of text.  I've got a regex that extracts 2 of those fields - file and extension.  I don't know how to extract the content text and I don't have a strategy for matching all characters except 'not a pattern'.

The pattern is: `var regex_file = /<!--<\|(.*)\.(.*)\|>-->/g,`

Also,  I'm not sure a regex is the best way to do this.  I considered the string method split: `split(regex_file)`

But I don't think there is a way to keep the delimiter one splits on.  It just returns the the content between the delimiter.  Also, I don't think there is a way to loop through `split()` as I did through `exec()` below.

What is the best way to extract these 3 fields from text in the structure below.  Further below is what I have so far.

**Text Structure**

```
<!--<|file.extension|>-->

// 1-10k of content text

<!--<|file.extension|>-->

// 1-10k of content text

<!--<|file.extension|>-->

// 1-10k of content text
```

**First Attempt**

```
    /*addNodes
    **
    **
    **
    */
    function addNodes(text) {
        var regex_file = /<!--<\|(.*)\.(.*)\|>-->/g,
            arr_file;

        while ((arr_file = regex_file.exec(text)) !== null) {
            arr_file[1] // holds file 
            arr_file[2] // holds extension
            arr_file[3] // need content here
        }
    }
```

**Additional Criteria:**

IE10+, FF10+, Safari5+, Chrome20+...Major Modern Browsers.

Comment: Can you give a short example of an input file, as well as what you expect as output?

Comment: Well then an example of output would help. The problem is that I can't tell what you want to pull from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.  The delimiter can be kept with regex:

```
s = "<!--<|file.extension|>--> // 1-10k of content text <!--<|file.extension|>--> // 1-10k of content text <!--<|file.extension|>--> // 1-10k of content text"
a = s.split(/<!--<\|([^.]*)(\.[^|]*)\|>-->/g)
for (i = 1; i < a.length; i += 3) {
  console.log('result:');
  console.log('  "'+a[i]  +'"');
  console.log('  "'+a[i+1]+'"');
  console.log('  "'+a[i+2]+'"');
}
```

output:

```
result:
  "file"
  ".extension"
  " // 1-10k of content text "
result:
  "file"
  ".extension"
  " // 1-10k of content text "
result:
  "file"
  ".extension"
  " // 1-10k of content text"
```

I was able to manually test it successfully for ie9, chrome23 on windows and chrome23, safari6, ff6 on on osx10.

I also threw it on browsershots.org and execution was successful for these versions:

firefox: 3.6.27 4.0.1 5.0.1 1.5.0.12 10.0.2 6.0.1 11.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0.1 17.0 7.0.1 15.0 16.0 2.0.0.20 8.0.1 9.0.1 18.0 17.0 19.0 3.6.28 16.0 9.0.1 10.0.2 17.0 6.0.2 7.0.1 8.0 12.0 14.0.1 13.0.1 4.0.1 15.0 5.0.1 3.0.10 19.0 18.0

msie: 10.0

safari: 3.2.3 5.1.7 5.1.7 6.0 5.0

chrome: 7.0.517.44 23.0.1271.101 17.0.963.56 8.0.552.224 17.0.963.56 22.0.1229.26 23.0.1251.2 22.0.1312.45 9.0.597.107 11.0.696.77 10.0.612.1 12.0.742.112 13.0.782.218 14.0.835.202 15.0.874.106 18.0.1025.33 19.0.1041.0 20.0.1132.57 21.0.1180.89 24.0.1312.45 23.0.1271.97 16.0.912.77 2.0.172.31 6.0.472.63

It was not successful for:
  chrome 20.0.1132.47 on ubuntu-12.04-lts

or versions of msie < 10

Comment: `Not all browsers support this capability` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Can you update your question to specify the browsers you're interested in?

Comment: Please update the question so that the acceptance criteria are clear.

Comment: AFAIK, Javascript's regex is part of the ECMA-262 standard.  If I understand [section 15.10.1 of the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) correctly, `[]` can contain `^`, `-`, `SourceCharacter but not one of \ or ] or -`, and `\ ClassEscape`.  A `SourceCharacter` is basically any unicode character, including `.`.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a way to loop through `split()`.

use java u can do it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text \n<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text \n<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text";
    String reg = "(?=\\n<!--<\\|[^<]*\\.[^>]*\\|>-->)";
    String[] split = text.split(reg);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
}
```

output

```
[<!--<|file.extension|>--> 
 1-10k of content text , 
<!--<|file.extension|>--> 
 1-10k of content text , 
<!--<|file.extension|>--> 
 1-10k of content text]
```

---

java script:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>

    function myFunction(){
        var reg = /(?=\n<!--<\|[^<]*\.[^>]*\|>-->)/;
        var text = "<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text \n<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text \n<!--<|file.extension|>--> \n 1-10k of content text";
        var n= text.split(reg);
        alert(n);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```